# SwiftUI: How can i change TabView height?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

I'd like to set a fixed height of 200 for my TabView.

```
    TabView {
        TabItem1().tabItem {
            Text("Tab1")
        }

        TabItem2().tabItem {
            Text("Tab2")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set frame for it, as below

```
TabView {
    Text("1").tabItem {
        Text("Tab1")
    }

    Text("2").tabItem {
        Text("Tab2")
    }
}
.frame(height: 200)
```

Comment: This sets the height of the _content_ of the tab view, not the tab view bar itself.

Comment: @damd, where did you read in question about tab bar?

Comment: Fair enough, maybe they indeed wanted to change the height of the tab view. Removing my downvote. Edit: Sorry, apparently I can't remove the downvote anymore. :(